# How to add more language in my Highlight.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight.js

Based on the code sample, how to add new language like c#, php, java, sql, etc. This sample was provided by a man who answered my question last month. I tried to add new languages but not working. Thanks.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

const removeTextNodes = el =>
   [...el.childNodes].forEach(child => child.nodeType !== 1 && el.removeChild(child))

const format = (text, language) => {
  switch (language) {
    case 'html': return html_beautify(text);
    case 'css': return css_beautify(text);
    case 'js': return js_beautify(text);
    default: return text;
  }
}

const preProcess = code => {
  removeTextNodes(code.closest('pre'));
  const language = [...code.classList].find(cls => /language-/.test(cls));
  const [ match, lang ] = language?.match(/language-(\w+)/);
  const content = code.innerHTML.trim();
  code.innerHTML = format(lang === 'html' ? _.escape(content) : content, lang);
};

const insertCode = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const content = e.target.elements.content.value.trim();
  const language = e.target.elements.language.value;
  if (content) {
    const formatted = format(content, language);
    const pre = document.createElement('pre');
    const code = document.createElement('code');
    code.classList.add(`language-${language}`, 'hljs');
    code.innerHTML = hljs.highlight(formatted, { language }).value;
    pre.append(code);
    container.prepend(pre);
  }
}

document.forms['add'].addEventListener('submit', insertCode);
document.querySelectorAll('code[class^="language-"]').forEach(preProcess);
hljs.highlightAll();
```

Comment: Your code is already setup to add new languages via the `language-${language}` class you add on the `code` element. What specifically is not working about that?

Comment: Also note that a list of the available languages and their classes is available from the highlight,js demo page: https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/

Comment: In my html i have a select tag with 3 options with a value: html , css, and js. Now, what i want to do is to add another option. Lets say its java and c#, then i have to do this => <option value="cs">C#</option><option value="java">Java</option> <= . Then on my javascript at format function, i add a new case like this => case 'java': return java_beautify(text);     but its not working when i select the java option. it doesn't print anything. My question is what should i do to my javascript/jquery to make it work? I asked the one who gave me this but he didnt answer my question.

Comment: my full html below

Answer (score 1):

You can check the loaded languages with
`hljs.listLanguages()`

If this list doesn't contain the language, you want to use, you can load your language script-wise.

For example i wanted to use latex, so i added this script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.7.0/languages/latex.min.js"></script>
```